# Passing php variable as hidden input where html is contained in one echo

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnLogin'])){
    $myVariable = $_POST['fieldParameter'];

    if(condition){
        //do something
    }else{

      echo "  
        <form method='POST' action='submit.php'><br/>       
          <input type='hidden' name='myVariable' value='<?php echo $myVariable; ?>'/>
          <br/>
          <input type='submit' name='btnSubmit' id='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>

          ";
        }
}
?>
```

Notice that the variable `$myVariable` is contained in the main `IF` block. I'm trying to send the value of `$myVariable` to **submit.php** as hidden field.

Also, i enclosed all the html tags using one `echo` statement with double quotes.

I found related questions here in `SO` but can't find similar to embedding `php` within a long `echo` of `html` tags

I tried to put `value='<?php echo $studentNo; ?>'` with no success.

I want to access it in a **submit.php** file like this,

**submit.php**

```
<?php 
    $aVariable = $_POST['myVariable'];
    echo $aVariable;
?>
```

How can I pass the value contained in `$myVariable` as hidden field? Is there something wrong with the way I use double and single quotes?

Comment: You just need to type `$myVariable` instead of `<?php echo $myVariable ?>` in your string. Double quotes `""` only creates a string literal. It doesn't directly output data like inline HTML. As you can see from the syntax coloring in StackOverflow, the `<?php` inside a string is sent as-is. You can also see this via view-source in your browser.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried this <input type='hidden' name='studentNo' value='$studentNo'/> and it worked.

Comment: looks like it worked with single quotes while being contained in one long echo " //html here <input type='hidden' name='studentNo' value='$studentNo'/>  ";

Comment: I am referring to the double quotes that embed your whole HTML output.

Comment: @PEMapModder Sure. I appreciate the help. :) Need to study more about Php. Things are a bit different compared to Java. I guess I'm looking for access modifiers and class attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to type $myVariable instead of  in your string. Double quotes "" only creates a string literal. It doesn't directly output data like inline HTML. As you can see from the syntax coloring in StackOverflow, the

You can try these variants (simplified):

```
// code before
echo "<input type='hidden' name='myVariable' value='$myVariable'/>";
// code after

// OR //

// code before
?>
<input type='hidden' name='myVariable' value='<?= $myVariable ?>'/>
<?php
// code after
```

Note that the quotes you use in HTML don't affect PHP, as long as you escape them properly (use `\"` and `\'` where appropriate).

Answer (score 4):

If you are already echoing a string you shouldn't put `<?php echo "" ?>` inside it again. You should concatenate your string instead. But in your case you don't even need to do that, because you're using double quotes for echoing which means you can simply just write your variable in it.

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='submit.php'><br/>       
      <input type='hidden' name='myVariable' value='$myVariable;'/>
      <br/>
      <input type='submit' name='btnSubmit' id='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>";
```

If you were using single quotes for your `echo`, it would look like this:

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="submit.php"><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="myVariable" value="' . $myVariable . '"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>';
```